# xcode internal error "The event stream <DTFileSystemEventStream"

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode3.2

I get the following error when i open this xcode project

[image: xocde startup error]

I have tried doing a "xcodebuild -activetarget -configuration Debug" from the command line also and i get the same error with a stacktrace

```
2010-07-14 12:55 xcodebuild[4991] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught Exception **
Exception: The event stream <DTFileSystemEventStream: 0x11497dfb0> could not be started.
Stack:
  0  0x00007fff87af6d06 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff806c90f3 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x000000010002a3b6 -[DTFileSystemEventStream start] (in DevToolsFoundation)
  3  0x000000010014ef73 -[XCFileSystemWatcher registerWatcher:forPaths:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x000000010016e24b -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x000000010016476f -[PBXTarget propagateTargetSnapshotIfNeeded] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x00000001001f2a2a -[PBXTarget(XCBuildables) prepareForBuildingWithBuildOperation:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x0000000100351725 -[XCBuildOperation _setupBeforeRunning] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x00000001001f1923 -[XCBuildOperation setupBeforeRunning] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x00000001000076fa
 10  0x00000001001f1300 -[XCOperation run] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x00000001001f0c1f -[XCOperation runWhenReady] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x00000001001f0ba0 -[XCBuildOperation runWhenReady] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x0000000100008760
 14  0x000000010000bfac
 15  0x0000000100001b7c
 16  0x0000000000000004
```

I cannot get this thing to do anything, i have tried cleaning, building,  any ideas ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to get this error after a snow leopard update installs, and it's incredibly frustrating. What's happening is that the CarbonCore function FSEventStreamStart is making an rpc call to the fsevenstd process to monitor changes in a particular directory. If you tail -f /var/log/system.log while trying to run Xcode, you may see something like the following:

fseventsd[151]: implementation_added_client : failed to add client for path

What I did was to go into my project.pbxproj and remove the offending entry from the section that starts with "/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */" near the top of the file.

I then restarted Xcode, no dialog box, so I exited it gracefully. I then restored the project.pbxproj from source control, started xcode and the problem seemed to vanish.

I wish I knew why fseventsd had problems with those entries - one thing that they had in common was that they were resource/bundle directories.

Hope this works for you